# Can't receive broadcast intent ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE

Tags: android, android-intent, android-broadcastreceiver

I am trying to receive ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE 
**Please note that download is initiated by chrome and then taken over by DownloadManger.**

---

here is my relevant manifest.xml

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> 
<application>
    <receiver
        android:name=".receivers.DownloadBroadcastReceiver"
        android:directBootAware="true"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>
```

---

Here is the DownloadBroadcastReceiver

```
public class DownloadBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
 @Override
 public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
     Log.i("TAG", "onReceive: A download happened");
 }
}
```

**EDIT :** I tried adb to send intent

> `adb -d shell am  broadcast -a android.intent.action.DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE`

and then my app responds, looks like DownloadMangeris not sending the intent.

Comment: [probably duplicut](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16042000/app-not-receiving-android-intent-action-download-complete-intent)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [App not receiving android.intent.action.DOWNLOAD\_COMPLETE intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16042000/app-not-receiving-android-intent-action-download-complete-intent)

Comment: @sanemars android.permission.SEND_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETED_INTENTS is level 2 permission and I cannot get that one, moreover, I already said, my app is not initiating the download.